# Should I use @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type eslint's rule?

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style, eslint

I've started working on a project which has this eslint rule enabled ([@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md)) and I was wondering what value it provides?

From my personal experience, I feel like this rule doesn't provide much value and adds boilerplate in 99% of the cases. I think disabling it and only specifying types when they can't be inferred would be a better approach. Thought on this?

Comment: Linter rules are always personal preference. If you find value in a rule - use it. If you think it detracts value - turn it off. If you don't care - don't do anything with it. Everything since JSLint onwards has had the same core idea - don't force yourself to follow rules that are somebody else's preference. Or in other words, don't be JSLint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also believe that it is redundant. But only if you use `--noImplicitAny`. We all know that using `any` is a criminal offence in TypeScript, right? (Attempted joke)

So since TypeScript doesn't allow implicit `any`s, everything is sensibly typed (unless you specify `any` explicitly, so add es-lint `no-explicit-any` to avoid prison time), TypeScript will make sure that all the function returns are properly typed and used accordingly.

And this way we gain more flexibility when having to change function signatures. Imaging changing `id: number` to `id: string` in all the project? So for more flexibilty you can also use `id: Entity["id"]` - longer to write but never breaks.

Comment: I really like syntax like `Entity["id"]`. It's flexible and it also brings information about the context of function.